# На чем пишут калькулятор доставки?

Tags: javascript

Скорее всего скрипт, но как понимаю, есть варианты с использованием обращений к БД, либо без него. Хотелось бы конечно без, но в чем плюсы с БД и различия сложностей - можно сообщить)
Итоговым вариантом такого калькулятора хотелось бы видеть функционал как у крупных транспортных компаний - ДЛ, желдор, пэк..
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сервер - место, где можно закрыться за железной дверью и никто тебя не достанет. Поэтому считать что-то на клиенте (js), а тем более цену и доверять ей - плохая идея. Лучший вариант - считать все и на клиенте (для быстроты и UX) и пересчитывать на сервере (для безопасности).

И так, можно каждому значению поля ввода присвоить атрибут коэффициента (отрицательное или положительное число), например, который будет за счет перемножения на значение поля либо увеличивать либо уменьшать итоговую сумму. В конце все эти произведения нужно сложить и получить конечный результат. Тривиальный пример, но приблизительно так все работает:

```js
$("input, select").on("input change", () => {
  let total = 0;
  $("input, select").each((index, item) => {
    let elem = $(item);
    let val = Number(elem.val());
    let multiply = Number(elem.attr("data-multiply"));
    total += (val * multiply);
  });
  $("#total").html("Итого: " + total);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 60%;
}

body>*:not(span) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Чило во мне перемножится на 200</span>
<input data-multiply="200" type="number">
<span>Чило во мне перемножится на 2 (0 - 100)</span>
<input data-multiply="2" type="range" value="0">
<select data-multiply="1.2">
  <option value="0">Чило во мне увеличится на 20%</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
</select>

<span id="total">Итого: </span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, направление понял, но все равно еще много вопросов, и наверно самый главный такой: а как быть с городами (пунктами) отправки и назначения, как их привязать? Это уже аякс?

Comment: @Serj по идее это все аякс, потому что вы будете все пересчитывать на сервере, и серверу удобнее взять все множители из базы, а чтобы эти множители совпадали с теми, что будут на клиенте, клиенту тоже их нужно отдать из этой же базы (и далее при любых изменениях множителей они будут синхронизированы на сервере и на клиенте). По крайней мере я так вижу. Города тоже могут храниться в базе с указанием их "цены". Тут все очень индивидуально, не думаю, что есть какие-то стандартные способы создания таких калькуляторов.